# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject knowing class name (string)

Tags: json, vb.net, reflection

I've a vb.net class that includes some serializable sub-classes

```
Public Class Model
    <Serializable>
    Public class foo
        Public Property id as Integer
        Public Property name as String
    End Class

    <Serializable>
    Public Class bar
        Public Property grading as Integer
        Public Property minWage as Decimal
        Public Property maxWage as Decimal
    End Class
End Class
```

Now I receive from a web service, an object (as json formated string) and its class name (as string) and I'd like to Deserialize it as my object.

I could do, as it is actually working, a

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
    
Public Shared Function Deserialize(ByVal Json As String, ByVal name As String) As Object
   
    Select Case name
        Case "foo"
            Return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(of Model.foo)(Json)
        Case "bar"
            Return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(of Model.bar)(Json)
    End Select
End Function
```

But as you can imagine, I've a ton of classes, not just 2, so I tried to use Reflection

```
Imports System.Reflection
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Public Shared Function Deserialize(ByVal Json As String, ByVal name As String) As Object

    Dim assembly As Assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(GetType(Model))
    Dim type As Type = assembly.[GetType]("Model." & name) ' Why is this always Nothing?
    Dim objInstance As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(type)
    '        objInstance = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of ???)(Json)

    Return objInstance 
End Function
```

But on one hand the type variable is always Nothing, and on the other hand, I don't know what to put instead of the comment.

Can you please advise ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the Namespace where the `Model` class is defined.
A nested class is separated by a `+`, so you have to add that to the full name of the Class object you want to create.

The composed string is then `"[Namespace].[ClassName]+[NestedClassName]"`

You don't need to create the instance, the Json Serializer will do that for you. Pass the Type of the class to the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()` method that accepts a Type as the second parameter.

```
Public Shared Function Deserialize(Json As String, className As String) As Object
    Dim asm = Assembly.GetAssembly(GetType(Model))
    Dim t As Type = asm.GetType($"{asm.GetName().Name}.Model+{className}")
    Return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Json, t)
End Function
```

How you're going to use this, it's up to you :)

More *generic*:

```
Public Shared Function Deserialize(Of T)(Json As String, className As String) As Object
    Dim asm = Assembly.GetAssembly(GetType(T))
    Dim t1 As Type = asm.GetType($"{asm.GetName().Name}.{GetType(T).Name}+{className}")
    Return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Json, t1)
End Function
```

Call as:

```
Dim deserialized = Deserialize(Of Model)(Json, "foo")
```

Comment: Oh that looks so great. Let me try that now!

Comment: My massive Select Case of 62 entries is thanking you!

Answer (score 0):

I've partially solve my problem, I can now crerate the right object, like so

```
Dim objType As Type = (From asm In AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() From type In asm.GetTypes() Where type.IsClass AndAlso type.Name = name Select type).Single()
Dim objInstance As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(objType)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my final, working function, thanks to Jimi!

```
Public Shared Function Deserialize(ByVal Json As String, ByVal name As String) As Object
    Try
        Dim objType As Type = (From asm In AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() From type In asm.GetTypes() Where type.IsClass AndAlso type.Name = name Select type).Single()

        Return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Json, objtype)

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception("Unknown class")
    End Try
End Function
```